# Any significance as to why the sheriff's name in Cut Bank is Vogel?

Tags: character, analysis, cut-bank

In many plays, novels etc character names are of some sort of significance. 
I noticed that in [Cut Bank](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1661820/), the sheriff's name is Vogel which means bird in German/Dutch.

Is there a connection to his personality, job etc?

Comment: Robert Patino worked on "Sons of Anarchy" with a Stuntman called [Torrey **Vogel**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2934282/?ref_=nmmd_md_nm). The choice of name may have been connected in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This is a little tenuous so please bear with me.

Roberto Patino has been exposed to the name "Vogel" twice in his career, once on the set of 'Sons of Anarchy' where he worked alongside [Torrey Vogel](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2934282/?ref_=nmmd_md_nm) during the period when he was writing the script for Cut Bank. He also went to USC for a year in 2008-2009 where he would have been a contemporary of [Jillian Vogel](https://www.linkedin.com/in/vogeljillian) although I've found no evidence that they knew each other (in a department with over 500 students).

---

As to whether the name Vogel (e.g. "*Bird*") fits the characterisation, the answer is a firm 'No'.

> INT. STEELEY HOME - LIVING ROOM - LATER
>
> Big Stan opens the door to SHERIFF VOGEL, 56, a **once-burly, now thin and worn man in jeans and flannel. Heavy eyelids hang over his eyes. A grave countenance.**
>
> He flips his key ring around his finger incessantly. On the key ring is a DIRTY
> GRAY-BROWN RABBIT FOOT.